# How to fetch all datas and images from mysql tableusing PDO?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get a list of news from MySQL but I have some issues with PDO and I can not get. Actually I have titles, messages, photos and categories. Please see the code below and if you can help me. Images are in folder named 'userdatas'

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM news");
$sth->execute();
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['title'];
    echo $row['category'];
    echo $row['message'];
    echo '<img src="' . $row['photo'] . '" height="60" width="40"> ';
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Does the photo column on the database include the full path to the image, or just the image name?

Comment: what is in the `photo` column ?

Comment: Its image-name, I can list all information's except images.

Comment: Tip: Not use the `*` for the queries, this result to bad performance.

Comment: @TimeToCode while I agree with you I think he literally want to select everything

Comment: don't just store the image name also store the fullpath on ur db

Comment: Perhaps give an example  of `echo $row['photo']; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the above code is that you are only specifying the image name. You need something that will specify the full path to the image like this:

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM news");
$sth->execute();
 while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['title'];
    echo $row['category'];
    echo $row['message'];
    echo '<img src="PATH/TO/IMAGE/' . $row['photo'] . '" height="60" width="40"> ';
    echo "<br>";
```

All you need to do is replace PATH/TO/IMAGE with the actual folder path, or change the database to include the full path